# I need to return list 1 index and list 2 index, when list 1 matches with list 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to return the index in list 1 and list 2, when list 1 matches with list 2
I have a code like:

```
def list_contains(List1, List2): 
    id1=0
    id2=0
  
    # Iterate in the 1st list 
    for idx, m in enumerate(List1): 
  
        # Iterate in the 2nd list 
        for idx2, n in enumerate(List2): 
    
            # if there is a match
            if m != n:
                None
            
            else:
                id1 = idx
                id2 = idx2
                
                
                  
    return (id1,id2)
      
List1 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']  
List2 = ['s','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']  
print(list_contains(List1, List2))
```

what to change here , so i can get all the matching indexes...

Comment: Which python version are you actually using here? You've listed both 2.7 and 3.x which is not possible.

Comment: try creating a dictionary list element as key and index as value

Comment: What's your actual vs. desired output?

Comment: @TheGrandJ its 3.x

Comment: @MarkTolonen i need all the indexes Atual : (1,5) expected (0,1) and (1,5)

Comment: Can elements in this list repeat? If there are two 'a' in either the first or second list, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the matching indexes to a list. Create empty list and add all matching indexes to it. finally return the list.

```
res = []
# Iterate in the 1st list 
for idx, m in enumerate(List1): 
    # Iterate in the 2nd list 
    for idx2, n in enumerate(List2): 
        # if there is a match
        if m != n:
            None
        else:
            res.append((idx, idx2))
```

or You can use `yield`

```
for idx, m in enumerate(List1): 
    # Iterate in the 2nd list 
    for idx2, n in enumerate(List2): 
        # if there is a match
        if m != n:
            None
        else:
            yield (idx, idx2)
```

then convert the result to `list`

```
print(list(list_contains(List1, List2)))
```

Efficient solution would be using a dictionary. Create dictionary with `List2` where list element is key and index is value. This will work if `List2` has no duplicates.

```
def list_contains(List1, List2): 
    d = {x: idx for idx, x in enumerate(List2)}
    return [(idx, d[y]) for idx, y in enumerate(List1) if y in d]
```

Answer (score 1):

basically this:

```
for each in List1:
  if each in List2:
    id1.append(List1.index(each))
    id2.append(List2.index(each))
return (id1,id2)
```

oh ok, this then:

```
List1 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
List2 = ['s','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
matches = []

for each in List1:
    if each in List2:
        matches.append(str(List1.index(each)) + str(List2.index(each)))
print(matches)
```

Comment: I think OP wants a list of matching index pairs, not two lists of matches.

Answer (score 1):

this will provide you the indexes in each list

```
List1 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
List2 = ['s', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
List3 = []
for num1, l1 in enumerate(List1):
    for num2, l2 in enumerate(List2):
        if l1 == l2:
            List3.append((num1, num2))
print(List3)
```

the output will be:
[(0, 1), (1, 5)]

Answer (score 0):

To get all matches you are very close to what you want to do. Rather than do it externally I would suggest you do this

```
List1 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']  
List2 = ['s','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
List3 = []

for x in List2:
    for y in range(len(List1)):
        if x = List1[y]
          List3.append(y)

print(List3)
```

This will simply loop through each value of the second List and compare it to all the elements of the first list. If they match it will then store the index of the first list that matched. This is then outputted at the end.

I have assumed as per your example that you want the index based off of the first list.

IF you want to get both indexes then you can modify it as such

```
List1 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']  
List2 = ['s','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
List3 = []

for x in range(len(List2)):
    for y in range(len(List1)):
        if List2[x] = List1[y]
            List3.append(List2[x] + ',' + List1[y])

print(List3)
```

This will result in string comma separated answers. If you do not want this then simply remove the +','+ and put in a ,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to **return/yield** the index values when the values match for both List1 and List2:

```py
def list_contains(List1, List2):

    for index, val in enumerate(zip(List1, List2)):
        if val[0]==val[1]:
            yield index
```

`yield` gives you a *generator* object. Iterate over the generator object like any other iterator to get the values:

```py
matching_index = list_contains(list1, list2)
for index_values in matching_index:
   print(index_values)
```